# Remove sections from a text file not containing certain strings

Tags: linux, text, replace, formatting, cut

So I have a text document with information associated with emails. and I have another one with a list of emails.

Now I want to basically check to see if an email matches one in a field of document one(separated by the "====")  and If it does contain an email from document two, then outputs/saves that specific field (with the data).

So for example,

document A:

```
===================
JohnDoe@gmail.com
Tall man
Black hair
Blue eyes
===================
====================
jackandjones@gmail.com
Small man
Black hair
green eyes
=====================
=====================
janedoe@gmail.com
Tall women
Ginger hair
Blue eyes
=====================
```

Document two:

```
Johndoe@gmail.com
bobdylan@gmail.com
Janedoe@gmail.com
```

Desired output:

```
===================
JohnDoe@gmail.com
Tall man
Black hair
Blue eyes
===================
=====================
janedoe@gmail.com
Tall women
Ginger hair
Blue eyes
=====================
```

Sorry if I am not explaining this well, What jumps to mind is using cut command but I can't get my head around getting my desired output, could anyone give me a nudge?

Answer (score 0):

assuming GNU `awk` with the `RS` support of multi-characters AND `RT`

```sh
gawk '
FNR==NR { f1[tolower($1)];next}
!(FNR%2) && tolower($2) in f1 { print RT $0 RT }
' DocumentTwo RS='[=]+' FS='\n' DocumentA
```

yields:

```
===================
JohnDoe@gmail.com
Tall man
Black hair
Blue eyes
===================
=====================
janedoe@gmail.com
Tall women
Ginger hair
Blue eyes
=====================
```